# Limits of SQL IN statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to maintain an application of mass email sender. The last programmer did a nice job, but the boss feel that a little optimizations could be done on the database treatment. When a campaing is finished, the report gives the option to save the selected segment. For instance, we send 50000 emails, and we want to save the segment of people who open the newsletter (2000) The tool now creates a new segment duplicating the contacts (with an INSERT), but I think we could improve the tool by saving the id of each contact.

I would like to know if saving the contacts whith an sql IN statement would increase the performance of the tool, or there is another way to perform this. Something like:

1. Create a list of the ids of the contacts SELECT * FROM contacts
2. SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE idContact IN (all_contacts_comma_separated) --> I would save
   this

Thanks in advance

PD: It's a production environment, so I need to be sure before made any changes :-(

Comment: I'd recommend mirroring the production environment in a development sandbox before doing anything else.

Comment: `For instance, we send 50000 emails` I really wish this were completely illegal and impossible

Comment: Hi. It's not impossible and we only send to double opt-in people, so it's not illegal. However, the legal part resides on my boss, and I think this is cover enough... Or I will change of job soon :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say where the list of people who opened the email currently resides. If it's not in the database what code/process will you use to generate your `IN` statement list? If it is in the database why not `JOIN` your tables to get the information?

Either way I'd not recommend using `IN` when you have 2000 items in the list.

It might also be worth you reading the following:

[SQL Server: JOIN vs IN vs EXISTS - the logical difference](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx)

It's written with SQL server in mind (and I'm not sure it all directly applies to MySQL) but the concepts are interesting and you should perform testing before changing your production environment, as eggyal's comment suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The database resides in another table that has the result of the campaings. From here, we could take all of the info that we need to perform the reports. So I think I could make a JOIN on this table to fetch the emails. I am going to ask for a preproduction enviroment to perform the changes ans test the results.

Comment: 2000 is probably a little bit too much, I'd batch around 500-1000.  You'd need to test to find the best size.